# Soap with 'Distance Matrix' service

Tags: web-services, soap, google-maps-api-3

I want to research the 'Distance Matrix' service

Can i load the 'Distance Matrix' service to soap?

I try to put this URL in Initial and it's not worked..

Comment: the URL: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it worked

I was **able** to put the Distance Matrix in Soap